# Grails: error in SQL syntax when using MYISAM dialect

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grails: error in SQL syntax when changing the hibernate dialect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077148/grails-error-in-sql-syntax-when-changing-the-hibernate-dialect)

I am using Grails with mySQL database and I am trying to change the database engine. As far as I researched this can be done best with

```
 dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.[MyDialect]"
```

in the DataSource.groovy config. But when I set the dialect to org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLMyISAMDialect creation of my table fails with error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'type=MyISAM' at line 1

I also tried to alter the table later with:

sql.execute("ALTER TABLE book ENGINE = MYISAM;")

and this actually works but all the foreign keys are dropped for the table when changing the engine after the creation.

How should I avoid the error and change the engine normally?

Answer (score 1):

pav,

I am running MySQL 5.5.25, Grails 2.1.0, and grails hibernate-2.1.0 plugin, which uses hibernate-core 3.6.10.FINAL under the covers.

This may be an issue with your version of Grails (well, more specifically the underlying version of Hibernate that Grails is using) and your version of MySQL.

Here is a bug reported on [Hibernate JIRA: HHH-5988](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-5988).

I am using InnoDB as my engine, and I tried swapping in MyISAM as follows in my `DataSource.groovy`:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    // dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"
    dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLMyISAMDialect"
    username = "study"
    password = "********"
}
```

and I got errors upon table creation as well.

Here is a sample of one of the errors I get, which corresponds to the bug reported on Hibernate JIRA:

```
| Error 2012-08-22 13:15:12,739 [pool-4-thread-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  
- Unsuccessful: create table user (id bigint not null auto_increment, 
version bigint not null, 
login varchar(255) not null unique, 
password varchar(255) not null, 
role varchar(5) not null, 
primary key (id)) type=MyISAM
```

One of the comments on the aforementioned Hibernate JIRA bug is a user who is creating his own [custom dialect for MySQL 5 MyISAM](http://code.google.com/p/snofyre/source/browse/trunk/snomed-osgi/uk.nhs.cfh.dsp.snomed.persistence/src/main/java/uk/nhs/cfh/dsp/snomed/persistence/orm/MySQL5MyISAMDialect.java).